# SQL Query For pagination has Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using T-SQL for pagination like this

```
SELECT @PageSize = 4,
@Page = 1;
SELECT T.* FROM (((SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 'T' ORDER BY ID) AS 
RowIndex, * FROM VideoGallery) AS T
INNER JOIN Video_Category ON T.ID = Video_Category.VideoID)
INNER JOIN VCategories ON VCategories.Name = N'catname' AND 
Video_Category.CategoryID = VCategories.ID)
WHERE T.RowIndex BETWEEN ((@Page - 1) * @PageSize + 1) AND (@Page * 
@PageSize);
```

result is like:

```
ROWINDEX     NAME
   1        backup
   2        email   
   3        fax
   4        GSM
   5        backup
   6        email   
   13       fax
   18       GSM
```

Problem: in page number 2 only shown 2 result 
i want to show ROWINDEX 13 and 18 be in page 2

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect reslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

ORDER BY ******

OFFSET @ItemsPerPage * (@CurrentPage - 1) ROWS

FETCH NEXT @ItemsPerPage ROWS ONLY

```
DECLARE @Page int = 1;
DECLARE @PageSize int = 4;

SELECT T.* FROM (((SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 'T' ORDER BY ID) AS 
RowIndex, * FROM VideoGallery) AS T
INNER JOIN Video_Category ON T.ID = Video_Category.VideoID)
INNER JOIN VCategories ON VCategories.Name = N'catname' AND 
Video_Category.CategoryID = VCategories.ID)

ORDER BY T.ID
OFFSET @PageSize * (@Page - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

@MorteZa SenFi; have a look at this mock up. I think the issue might actually be from your definition of RowIndex (you should use ROW_NUMBER rather than RANK. Check that the RowIndex Column is actually sequential and consecutive.

[image]

See a simple example below:

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 3
DECLARE @Page INT = 2;


DECLARE @tblVideoGallery TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @tblVideoGallery
SELECT 1,'backup' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'email' UNION ALL   
SELECT 3, 'fax' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'GSM' UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 'backup' UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 'email'  UNION ALL   
SELECT 7, 'fax' UNION ALL 
SELECT 8, 'GSM'






SELECT T.* 
FROM (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowIndex, *
FROM @tblVideoGallery

) T
--INNER JOIN Video_Category ON T.ID = Video_Category.VideoID)
--INNER JOIN VCategories ON VCategories.Name = N'catname' AND 
--Video_Category.CategoryID = VCategories.ID)
WHERE T.RowIndex BETWEEN ((@Page - 1) * @PageSize + 1) AND (@Page * 
@PageSize);
```

See result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This query fails becasue your `join`s filter out some row numbers, so the aren't consecutive and can have gaps between.

I have rewritten your query with proper indentation and removed unnecessary query nestings. Give it a try:

```
SELECT @PageSize = 4, @Page = 1;
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT vg.*,
         RANK() OVER(/*PARTITION BY 'T' */ORDER BY vc.VideoID) AS RowIndex
  FROM VideoGallery AS vg
  INNER JOIN Video_Category vc ON vg.ID = vc.VideoID
  INNER JOIN VCategories vc2 ON vc2.[Name] = N'catname' AND vc.CategoryID = vc2.ID
) a
WHERE RowIndex BETWEEN ((@Page - 1) * @PageSize + 1) AND (@Page * @PageSize);
```

Also, I have commented part of a code here `RANK() OVER(/*PARTITION BY 'T' */ORDER BY ID)`, uncomment it, if you really want to.